# IE does not load the image

Tags: java, internet-explorer

[image: error]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/performer/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getPortfolioFile(HttpServletResponse response,
                                 @PathVariable("id") int id){

        File image = getFile(id);
        if(image != null){
            try {
                FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(image), response.getOutputStream());
                String mimeType = image.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                response.setContentLength((int)image.length());
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + image.getName() + "\"");
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see in the response there is an image but it does not shown on the page

this method works perfect for FF, Chrome, Opera but it does not work in IE.
i use IE v10.

Comment: and if you drop the `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition"...` line?

Comment: @wero, does not help

Comment: in any case you should change the order: first set the headers, then write the content to the outputstream (else the headers could be silently dropped if the content is longer than the response buffer)

Comment: @wero, thank you so much. you very help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order: First write the headers

```
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setContentLength((int)image.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + image.getName() + "\"");
```

then the content

```
FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(image), response.getOutputStream());
String mimeType = image.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
```

Else if the image is larger than the response buffer, the headers are silenty dropped and not sent since the response is already committed.

The browser may then be confused about the sent content.